# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in react app

Tags: node.js

node -v 12.16.1
npm -v 6.13.4
node-gyp -v 3.8.0

Failed to compile.

./src/util/firebase.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/app' in 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\atlas9\src\util'

not able to find way for setup project.

Comment: answer me fast . it will help me a lot.

Comment: Read the guide below and ask questions.
If you want a quick and accurate answer, provide your exact situation and high-quality information. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)